# Macro ignoring last parameter

Tags: c++, macros

I wrote a macro to replace the loop for, but I realized that it worked when I left the last parameter empty.

```
f(i, 0, 3) cout<<i;
output: 012

f(i, 3, =5) cout<<i;
output: 345

f(i, 4, 2) cout<<i;
output: 43

f(i, 3, ) cout<<i;
output: 321 //it understands that the limit is 0
```

I'd like to know **why this happens** and if this **can be done** with the second or the first parameters.

This is the macro and its quite big, so I'll split into lines

```
#define f(v, s, e) for(int v=s,                  \        s is the start value      
                           L1=atoi(&#e[0]),      \        L1 is the end value
                           K=s<L1?1:-1,                         \ K stores if s<e
                           L=L1+(#e[sizeof(#e)-2]=='='?K:0);    \ trick to check <= and >=
                           v!=L; v+= K)                       condition and increasing
```

Comment: And that is just one more example why macros are evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `e` is an empty list of tokens, `#e` is an empty string literal, `""`. `atoi(&#e[0])` is then effectively `atoi("")`, or 0 (`atoi` returns 0 on error).

`#e[sizeof(#e)-2]` expands to `""[sizeof("")-2]`, which exhibits undefined behavior. An empty string literal has the type of `const char[1]`, its size is 1, so you are trying to access an index of -1.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's look at the macro expansions, shall we?

```
// f(i, 0, 3) cout<<i;
for(int i=0, 
        L1=atoi(&"3"[0]),
        K=0<L1?1:-1,
        L=L1+("3"[sizeof("3")-2]=='='?K:0);
    i!=L;
    i+= K) cout<<i;

// f(i, 3, =5) cout<<i;
for(int i=3,
        L1=atoi(&"=5"[0]),
        K=3<L1?1:-1,
        L=L1+("=5"[sizeof("=5")-2]=='='?K:0);
    i!=L; i+= K) cout<<i;

// f(i, 4, 2) cout<<i;
for(int i=4,
        L1=atoi(&"2"[0]),
        K=4<L1?1:-1,
        L=L1+("2"[sizeof("2")-2]=='='?K:0);
    i!=L; i+= K) cout<<i;

// f(i, 3, ) cout<<i;
for(int i=3,
        L1=atoi(&""[0]),
        K=3<L1?1:-1,
        L=L1+(""[sizeof("")-2]=='='?K:0);
    i!=L; i+= K) cout<<i;
```

So what's happening is, when you leave the third parameter blank, it stringifies to the empty string, and `atoi("")` returns 0.  Note that `atoi("=5")` also evaluates to zero, which I *think* is not what you expected.  Note also that `""[sizeof("")-2]` is equivalent to `""[-1]` which provokes undefined behavior.  In summary, this does not actually work, it just seemed to work, by accident.

The first and second parameters are being used without stringification, so leaving them blank will be a syntax error.

Someone could conceivably come up with some clever template thingy that does what you *wanted* this to do, but you'd have to tell us what the behavior should be when the first and second parameters are empty.

Editorial aside: Please don't ever put code like this in "real" software.  If you're working on an [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) submission, on the other hand, go wild.

Comment: I would like, for example, to write f(i, ,n) and i starts on 0, just like the third parameter is doing

Comment: And if the first parameter is empty, what then?

Comment: dont know... nothing needs to happen :D hide the second and third parameters seemed nice if they were "magically" set to 0, but no deal with the first parameter

Comment: You specifically asked about leaving the first parameter blank, so to answer the question fully, we need to know what you want the effect of that to be!

Comment: I asked if the lack of parameter can be done with them too, but i'd like to hide only second or third